# Stop tidyverse from renaming column in lapply

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lapply, data-cleaning

When I use `group_by(col)` inside `lapply()`, columns `a` and `b` are renamed to `get(col)`. How do I stop this from happening? I would like to keep the original column names in the new objects.

**MRE**

Input

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 1), b = c(1, 1, 1), c = c(1, 1, 1))

lapply(c("a", "b"), function(col) {
  
  assign(col, df %>% group_by(get(col)) %>% summarize(), env = .GlobalEnv)
  
})
```

Output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  `get(col)`
       <dbl>
1          1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  `get(col)`
       <dbl>
1          1
```

It would be great if someone explained *why* this renaming occurs, in addition to how to stop it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm never a fan of using `assign`, especially with `envir=.GlobalEnv`. What are you trying to do that this is your path?

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `get` inside `group_by`. This doesn't play well with the non-standard evaluation. There are several options though.

You could use `!!ensym(col)`:

```r
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(col) {
  assign(col, df %>% group_by(!!ensym(col)) %>% summarize(), env = .GlobalEnv)
})
```

A similar approach is `!!str2lang(col)`

```
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(col) {
  assign(col, df %>% group_by(!!str2lang(col)) %>% summarize(), env = .GlobalEnv)
})
```

It seems however that the recommended methods are to use `pick(all_of(col))`

```r
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(col) {
  assign(col, df %>% group_by(pick(all_of(col))) %>% summarize(), 
         env = .GlobalEnv)
})
```

Or `across(all_of(col))`:

```r
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(col) {
  assign(col, df %>% group_by(across(all_of(col))) %>% summarize(), 
         env = .GlobalEnv)
})
```

The `group_by_at` function was ideal for this situation, but has been superseded and may soon be deprecated. In any case, all of these result in:

```r
a
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>       a
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1

b
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>       b
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
```

Note that it's considered bad practice to `assign` variables to the global workspace this way. It's almost always better to keep your results in a list:

```r
dfs <- lapply(c("a", "b"), function(col) {
  df %>% group_by(across(all_of(col))) %>% summarize()
  }) |>
  setNames(c("a", "b"))

dfs
#> $a
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>       a
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 
#> $b
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>       b
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Don't forget `.data[[col]]` which should probably be recommended above the other approaches you've given in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

Use `group_by_at` instead:

```
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(col) {
  
  assign(col, df %>% group_by_at(col) %>% summarize(), env = .GlobalEnv)
  
})

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 1
      a
  <dbl>
1     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 1
      b
  <dbl>
1     1
```

Comment: `group_by_at` has been superseded by `pick` or `across`.